# Why can't I install any gulp dependencies with npm?

Tags: npm, gulp

My computer crashed and now no install packages work at all.

This is what is shown in command line:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-autoprefixer
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-c
li.js" "install" "--save-dev" "gulp-autoprefixer"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! file C:\Users\buddy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\buddy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\buddy\Desktop\BuildTest\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I see a certain disturbing lack of `npm-debug.log`. Please [edit] to add that.

Comment: The npm-debug.log is extremely long that's why I didn't post it. Is there a character limit on here.

Comment: For future reference, there is, but 30k characters is usually enough. The trick is trimming down the log to the important parts just before the latest occurrence of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

`npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.`

That tells you everything you need to know. You need to make sure your `package.json` is valid JSON.

I would suggest linting it, perhaps through http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: i did lint it there was no issue. Although i fixed the problem by deleting my npm-cache folder everything seems to work right now @Nathan